# Flutter ios app rejected due to 'log in with apple' error only on iPad

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a flutter app both running on android and ios which were accepted to both markets.

To support share intent, I had to change some build settings on Xcode.

After the change, everything works well on my end (tested with the testflight version of the app).

However, the app is keep rejected due to `Sign in with Apple` isn't working on the iPad.

I don't have `iPad`, but I do have `iPad Air` and it works without the issue.

below is a screen from the apple review team

[image: Screen shot from apple review team]

Comment: I've got same rejection reason. Can you share me what you did to fix it?

Comment: You can resubmit the app, here's [an article](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/39828076.html)

Comment: try clean and rebuild it

Comment: So what I did is replied in the resolution center to review the app again with strong wifi or data connection. After few hours the status was updated to In Review again. Then within 5 mins the status updated to Ready for Sale. Miracle or what I don't know!

Comment: @Farwa I asked more question related to the rejection, then somehow it passed the review.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your app is working correctly on the iPad (I had to purchase an iPad to test this, then ended up returning it to Apple as I already own an Android tablet)

Then ask more question related to the rejection, I asked the exact model of the iPad they are testing, the iOS version, and asked them to test on different iPad.

Somehow, it passed the review afterwards.